# How can I display a property in options but get the id when selected

Tags: c#, knockout.js

this is my Student class (simplified)

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collections of object:

```
public JsonResult FetchSample()
{
    List<Students> students = StudentDataAccess.GetList();

    return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //this will be loaded in students ko.observableArray([])
}
```

I use knockoutjs viewmodel to get the list of students to the options. But how can I just display the LastName + ", " + FirstName but when I select an item, it will get the StudentId instead?

here is my knockoutjs viewmodel:

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(studVm);
    studVm.GetStudents();

});

var studVm =
{
    students: ko.observableArray([]),
    studentSelected: ko.observable(),
    GetStudents: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/OB/FetchSample',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application',
            success: function (data) {
                //  self.students.push(data);
                self.students(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my html

```
    <p>
        Student:
        <select data-bind="options: students, optionsCaption: 'Select student', value: studentSelected"></select>
    </p>

<button type="submit">SAVE</button>
```

UPDATE:

I added the button element: SAVE. Once I click save, this ActionResult method will be triggered:

```
public ActionResult FilePayment(Payment payment)
{
    PaymentContext db = new PaymentContext();
    Payment newPay = new Payment();

    newPay.StudentId = payment.StudentId; //this should be from the selected drop down list
    newPay.PayPrice = payment.PayPrice; //I just omitted the html element for this.

    db.Paymnents.Add(newPay);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the controller method?

Comment: just like this: public ActionResult OfficialBusinessFORM()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: the JsonResult takes care of the retrieving (which has no errors)

Comment: I mean,, where do you want to _"get the StudentId instead"_? What is your exact problem, you have tried something with no luck? please show us.

Comment: I updated the post for the controller

Comment: Does your `DropdownList` filled correctly?

Comment: no, unless i return a list of strings such as list of LastName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you have to create client side `Student` class (I will call it sub view model) which is matching with your server side `Student` class. Note that, client side Student class has to have a `fullName` property as below.

```
function Student(id, fName, lName) {
    this.studentId = id;
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.fullName = fName + ' ' + lName;
}
```

**Second**, edit you ajax success callback to create a `Student` array as below.

```
success: function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // please pay attention at the UPPER case/lower case below, it could be data[i].StudentId depends on your server JSON converter setting
        var student = new Student(data[i].studentId, data[i].lastName, data[i].firstName);
        self.students.push(student);
    }
}
```

**Last**, edit your binding as below.

```
<select data-bind="options: students, optionsText: 'fullName', optionsValue: 'id', value : studentSelected"></select>
```

I have created a CodePen here https://codepen.io/trgiangvp3/pen/veJryp